# How to make ttk.Notebook tab generate events both on entering and leaving?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I'd like a tab to read some data from ttk.Notebook (or an object/list/dict/whatever mutable passed to ttk.Notebook) when shown and writing data back when left. Here's my example

```
class TestTabs():
    class ManagerNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
        def __init__(self, master):
            ttk.Notebook.__init__(self, master)
            self.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.onTabChange)
            self.visit_str = 'viewed'
            self.leave_str = 'left'
            self.prev_id = [None] #mutable list

        def onTabChange(self, event):
            current_id = [event.widget.index("current")]
            event.widget.winfo_children()[current_id[0]].onVisibleIn(self, current_id[0], self.visit_str)
            if self.prev_id[0] is not None:
                event.widget.winfo_children()[self.prev_id[0]].onVisibleOut(self, self.prev_id[0], self.leave_str)
            self.prev_id[0] = current_id[0]

    class DispatcherTab(ttk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent
            ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            Label(self, text='Sample text').pack()

        def onVisibleIn(self, parent, id, str):
            print('%s is %s' % (parent.tab(id, 'text'), str))

        def onVisibleOut(self, parent, id, str):
            print('%s is %s' % (parent.tab(id, 'text'), str))

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.tabControl = self.ManagerNotebook(root)
        self.mainTab = self.DispatcherTab(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.mainTab, text='First tab')
        self.nextTab = self.DispatcherTab(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.nextTab, text='Second tab')
        self.tabControl.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def main():
    tk_root = Tk()
    test_gui = TestTabs(tk_root)
    tk_root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there an easier way to do what I want?

Comment: What do you dislike about it? It seems to be working correctly. Only thing that seems a bit oadd is casting your indices as lists.

Comment: I don't like two extra classes for a rather simple task and violation of encapsulation.  Yes, here the lists are redundant, but how to pass a list/dict stored in Notebbok-derived class correctly? Should I use getters/setters in the parent class?